# What is the difference between assigning machine to network by port or by network name?

Tags: openstack, terraform, ovh

I use Terraform trying to setup my infrastructure on OVH.

From docs I see that I can connect compute instance to network either by name:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "front" {
 network {
    name = "Ext-Net"
  }
}
```

or by port (then you need to create port entity):

```
data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "ext_net" {
  name      = "Ext-Net"
}

resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "public_port" {

  name               = "public_port"
  network_id         = "${data.openstack_networking_network_v2.ext_net.id}"
  admin_state_up     = "true"
}


resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "front" {
 network {
    port = "${openstack_networking_port_v2. public_port.id}"
  }
}
```

There is also a 3rd option (connect by network's uuid, but it is quite similar to network name).

In which case I should use port instead of network name?

Also when I connect both interfaces by name and ssh to freshly booted compute instance, I can see that ipv4 for internal network is not set as expected. Is it ok for OVH and I should set `10.0.0.1` manually with some kind of provisioning script?

```
network = [
  {
    name = "Ext-Net"
  },
  {
    name = "internal"
    fixed_ip_v4 = "10.0.0.1"
  }
]
```